# Word Export of SSRS Reporting Server different on two PCs

Tags: layout, reporting-services

I built an SSRS report for a client who runs SQL Server 2012. I developed the report on my local machine with SQL Server 2016. We both use VS 2013 Shell (Integrated). When exporting the report from the reporting portal (browser) to Word, the tables have different widths. The difference is minimal (e.g. 0,03cm over the entire table), but messes up the layout:

[Result my machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lU8x.png)

[Result client's PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJHMB.png)

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you both using the same browser to interact with SSRS? For example is one running chrome the other using internet explorer?

Comment: Hi Jon, no we're not. My client uses Firefox and I use Chrome. To test this, I just ran the report both in Firefox and Chrome on my machine and the tables have the same width...Not sure if it's because my client has a different Firefox version?!

Comment: Some browsers will render it differently, Firefox should have the same engine to render the page AFAIK. Most of the issues I've encountered were with the display in VS/SSDT to IE to Chrome